# static content in rails from .md file, suggestions for improvement?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, static, markdown

Using some code to read the content of .md files, I have 2 problems with current code:

1) no caching 
2) no content if there is no file ( instead of using :en language instead )

```
def show
    unless ['terms', 'privacy','press','cookies', 'help'].include?(params[:page])
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      begin
        # todo : add caching to this?
        @page   = File.read("#{Rails.root}/app/views/static/#{ params[:page] }.#{ locale }.md")
        @title  = File.open("#{Rails.root}/app/views/static/#{ params[:page] }.#{ locale }.md", &:readline)

        unless @page
          @page = "empty"
        end
        render :show
      rescue
        #redirect_to root_path
      end
    end
  end
```

Im using this to show some static content and be able to use .md files, any suggestions on how to improve this? What I don't like is that I need to load the title separately to be able to add some html/styling in between the title and the content.

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you save it to the database?

Also its not very secure, someone could inject a fake path in your params:

```
# imagine what happens if 
# params[:page] = "../../../../../etc/passwords" and locale is ""
@page   = File.read("#{Rails.root}/app/views/static/#{ params[:page] }.#{ locale }.md")
```

You could save the content in the database and query it via normal Md.find(id).

Comment: want to use .MD files for easy updating and formatting the contents

Comment: unless ['terms', 'privacy','press','cookies', 'help'].include?(params[:page]) *prevents* any non acceptable file to be included

Answer (score 0):

Using this:

EDIT #1
Not that great still but a small rewrite to at least be a bit more clean:

> ```
>   def show
>     unless ['terms', 'privacy','press','cookies', 'help'].include?(params[:page])
>       redirect_to root_path
>     else
>       begin
>         @content  = File.read("#{Rails.root}/app/views/static/#{ params[:page] }.#{ locale }.md")
>         @title    = File.open("#{Rails.root}/app/views/static/#{ params[:page] }.#{ locale }.md", &:readline)
>       rescue
>         @content  = File.read("#{Rails.root}/app/views/static/#{ params[:page] }.en.md")
>         @title    = File.open("#{Rails.root}/app/views/static/#{ params[:page] }.en.md", &:readline)
>       end
>       render :show
>     end
>   end
> ```

any suggestions welcome